# R - create date repetition over years

Tags: r, date, repeat

Based on a date range, for example,

```
my.date <- seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'),as.Date('2009-12-31'), by="days")
```

I need to create a repetition of the dates "October 1st" and "February 20st" over all the years in that range.

For the example provided, the result would be a data frame looking like this:

```
begin             end
2000-10-01        2001-02-20
2001-10-01        2002-02-20
2002-10-01        2003-02-20
2003-10-01        2004-02-20
2004-10-01        2005-02-20
2005-10-01        2006-02-20
2006-10-01        2007-02-20
2007-10-01        2008-02-20
2008-10-01        2009-02-20
```

The date ranges I have are pretty varied, so ideally I should be able to determine the initial and final years of the sequence automatically.

How to do that?

Comment: Your begin date is after your end date in each row. Is that they way it should be?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, thanks for pointing it out. I have edit the original question.

Comment: Just add years: `as.Date('2000-10-01') + lubridate::years(1:9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R method with `seq` and `as.Date`:

```
my.date.df <- data.frame(begin=seq(as.Date('2000-10-01'), 
                                   length.out=9, by="years"),
                         end=seq(as.Date('2001-02-20'),
                                   length.out=9, by="years"))
```

Here the by is replaced with "years".

```
my.date.df
        begin        end
1  2000-10-01 2001-02-20
2  2001-10-01 2002-02-20
3  2002-10-01 2003-02-20
4  2003-10-01 2004-02-20
5  2004-10-01 2005-02-20
6  2005-10-01 2006-02-20
7  2006-10-01 2007-02-20
8  2007-10-01 2008-02-20
9  2008-10-01 2009-02-20
```